# A sensible way to use data binding for a large software project.

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am looking into the logistics of adding several WPF features to a 1,000,000+ line code-base. I am looking into using databinding and DataTemplates in XAML to easily display various objects. I am able to bind an observable collection:  `points` to a ListBox and if I don't use a template, I can just provided a meaningful toString for the list items and that gets me somewhere. The problem comes in when I want to use a template to display various properties of the list items. It is my understanding that they all have to be DependencyProperties. `parent` is just a property. It looks like adding dependency properties is fairly complicated. All the classes you want to display have to inherit from `DependencyObject` and you have to set a bunch of stuff for each property you want to use. This does not seem feasible for a large codebase, to have to do all this for each property. 
I'm wondering how databinding is used in practice, do you really add crap-tons of dependency properties to all of your classes or is there a better way?

Thanks!

```
    <ListBox Name="listBox1" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource points}}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Point!"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding parent}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem comes in when I want to use a template to display various properties of the list items. It is my understanding that they all have to be DependencyProperties. parent is just a property. It looks like adding dependency properties is fairly complicated. All the classes you want to display have to inherit from DependencyObject and you have to set a bunch of stuff for each property you want to use.

This is not true.

You need to use a Dependency Property *or* have your type implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but this is only required if you want the binding to work bi-directionally.  This requirement exists so that WPF gets notified when a property value changes, and the UI can update automatically.  However, if the property value isn't changing while the screen is displayed, there is no requirement (other than the value be a Property, and not a Field).

If you're just displaying the values within the object, and they won't change while being displayed, standard properties will work fine.

Comment: Ok, that's good. So the above code produces a textblock that says Point! and a textblock that is empty so something isn't working. parent is declared like this: `private String parent { get; set; }` and the `points` has two items in it before InitializeComponent() is called.

Comment: @markv12 You probably need to set the DataContext of the window/page/usercontrol - That may be as simple as adding, right after `InitializeComponent(); this.DataContext = this;`  The DataContext is where the binding system "looks for" the property...

Comment: Ok, that didn't work, I think the issue is that I want the `parent` property of each item in the list, so the DataContext needs to change. The binding system needs to look in a different place each time. `Path="parent"` also doesn't work.